# Agent forwarding for AWS credentials?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-ssm, aws-sts

In SSH, there is an *agent forwarding* option to use local credentials, e.g. for working with services like GitHub or for chaining connections onward to log in to other servers, whereby the private key stays under the protection of the local OS keychain and no trusted private key material is ever present on the "jumpbox" or remote environment. Is anything analogous possible for AWS credentials?

For example, if connecting to an EC2 Instance with AWS SSM (or EC2 Instance Connect, or SSH via an SSM proxy tunnel, etc) is there any way to automatically transfer temporary AWS credentials to the remote session (or any way to proxy AWS SDK authentication calls back to the local system)?

I'm looking for an approach that can avoid needing to manually repeat the user authentication process twice (once locally and then again inside the remote session, potentially involving MFA each time). Ideally it would only provide temporary credentials to the remote session, and automate the temporary credential rotation to be transparent to applications (like how IRSA automatically rotates temporary AWS keys for AWS SDK based processes on EKS pods, except that IRSA uses k8s OIDC instead of depending on an active connection from an authenticated user). How could this be implemented?

Comment: Compute resources such as EC2 instances, ECS containers and Lambda functions typically receive their credentials via the assignment of IAM Roles to those resources. There should not be a need to 'pass credentials' to these remote systems. If you are wanting to override the IAM Roles and instead use particular credentials (eg from your IAM User), you would be responsible for providing those credentials either by storing the in the `~/.aws/credentials` file or by setting Environment Variables. See: [Configure the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html)

Comment: This is relevant where the EC2 instance is used as a devbox (a remote workstation, say in a corporate context with hot-desking, software restrictions on the local network, or underpowered local machines). If connecting with vanilla SSH then would only need activate developer credentials on the remote system, but if connecting with SSM then would need to activate credentials on both systems.

Comment: One option is to set Environment Variables in the target machine, which would be used by software using an AWS SDK. You could set these variables as the first commands when making the connection. See: [When ssh'ing, how can I set an environment variable on the server that changes from session to session?](https://superuser.com/q/163167/413312)

Answer (score 1):

You can give the ec2 an instance role with IAM permissions to access the required service and therefore do not use temporary AWS credentials. Then when you run aws cli commands or SDK programs in the ec2 instance it assumes the role and permissions of the instance role you setup. This is further secure over copying credentials from your local to the remote instance.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html

Comment: Yes, attaching roles to compute resources (EC2 instances, lambdas, ECS containers, k8s pods via IRSA, etc) is great because temporary credentials are generated and handled transparently by the SDKs. But these permissions ought to be narrowly scoped for their specific applications (for security), whereas roles associated with workforce user identities will have more general scope and so ought to be protected (e.g. with MFA to restrict use to an interactive session) rather than being left available to other processes while the operator is absent.

Answer (score 0):

**Background**

There are several mechanisms that the AWS SDKs (including the CLI) will consistently attempt for authorisation. Env vars and a config file will be checked, for either an access key or for details of an (OIDC) identity provider, before resorting to checking the EC2 or ECS metadata service.

There are also provisions (in the config file) for specifying an *arbitrary process* to obtain the credentials.

Note SSH does have facility for propagating some env vars to the remote session, but simply passing a static AWS access key in this manner would be limiting (as there would not be potential for refreshing short-term tokens nor for interactively switching between multiple AWS accounts/roles).

Reference:  [Generic SDK Credentials configuration docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/standardized-credentials.html)

**Solution**

One approach would be to script a local service (e.g., a simple *flask* app invoking *aws sts* commands) for producing temporary credentials on demand. Then connect to the remote instance by SSH proxied via SSM (potentially using EC2 Instance Connect to temporarily upload an SSH public key) and use an SSH tunnel so that the remote system can access the local credentials service as long as the session is active. Then modify the config on the remote system, to request credentials tunnelled from the local service (e.g.  via *curl localhost*). To prevent other simultaneous users of the remote system from also being able to retrieve credentials, an improvement would be to have SSH pass a *bearer token* or *nonce* into the remote session (e.g. as an env var). Another enhancement would be for the local service utility to support revoking the temporary credentials and switching (interactively from a UI on the local system) between different AWS accounts/roles.

This would allow the developer to log in just once for their organisation (leveraging MFA and SSO) then perform various work from remote interactive compute environments, retaining *convenient* granular control of delegated access, and minimising exposure for credential leaks.